# Difference between EC2 System Manager and OpsWork

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any difference between EC2 System Manager (State Manager, Run Command) and OpsWork regarding the functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpsWorks**: Customers who are looking for a configuration management experience that is fully compatible with Chef, including all community scripts and tooling, but without operational overhead should adopt OpsWorks for Chef Automate.

**Ec2 Systems Manager:**

The biggest limitations with AWS features of this type are usually a lack of 3rd-party extensions or support.

e.g. with Chef you have a massive resource of 3rd-party cookbooks freely available

This article could be useful for you:
[Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/60hqwb/anybody_using_ec2_systems_manager/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment_list)